# I can't set the img up on the grid

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm design a website for learning in React framework. Now, I'm styling the main part of the site, but I can't figure out how to set the img element to be aligned to the h1, h2, p and button.

```
import React from "react";
import mainImage from './assets/restauranfood.jpg'

function Main() {
    return (
        <main>
            <div className="main-grid">
                <h1>Little Lemon</h1>
                <h2>Chigago</h2>
                <p>Little Lemon is a charming neighborhood bistro that serves simple food and classic cocktails in a lively but casual environment. The restaurant features a locally-sourced menu with daily specials.</p>
                <button>Reserve a table</button>
                <img className="main-image" src={mainImage} />
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}

export default Main
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: 0;
}

.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.navigation a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Markazi Text', serif;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background-color: #FFE500;
}

.navigation a.active {
  background-color: #FFE500;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navigation {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    }

  .navigation a {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .navigation a:hover {
    padding: 10px;
  } 
}

.main-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #495E57;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  align-items: start;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;

}



.main-grid h1 {
  color: #FFE500;
  font-family: 'Markazi Text', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 64px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.main-grid h2 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Markazi Text', serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  align-self: start;
  grid-column: 1;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.main-grid p {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: 'Markazi Text', serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  grid-column: 1;
  width: 70%;

}

.main-grid button {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: #F4CE14;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Markazi Text', serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  grid-column: 1;
  width: 150px;
}

.main-grid > * {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.main-grid img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  grid-column: 3;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  padding-right: 100px;
}
```

[Actually output](https://imgur.com/a/H3UK8Jp)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFuyN.png)
[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lm9Q.png)

I have already tried to use flexbox and grid system and all the styling option, but I got stucked.

Comment: Actually, Your "Actual Output" link and "Desired Output" are identical, Please update it accordingly, So we can know your requirements and helps you out ! Thanks.

Comment: I just updated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can make your image postion:absolute  and edit the bottom:-40px for example

Comment: It worked, but the img was not responsive.

Comment: to make it responsive you have to use (**vw**) instead of (**px**)
of course you should also to use media queries for responsive design in your code like this for example `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)`